# OpenWRT Luci persistent install

Tags: installation, openwrt, luci

I have a TP-WR710N running OpenWRT.

When I install Luci via putty (CL), everything works as it should. However, after a reboot or unplugging the router - everything is reverted back to the default OpenWRT settings and luci has to be installed again.

Any ideas how to keep luci persistently installed, even after a reboot?

```
/etc/init.d/uhttpd enable
```

didn't work either :(

P.s. this goes the same for anything I install. For example: openvpn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after installing the firmware:

```
openwrt-ar71xx-generic-tl-wr710n-v1-squashfs-sysupgrade.bin
```

I installed:

```
openwrt-ar71xx-generic-tl-wr710n-v1-squashfs-factory.bin
```

via Luci and it doesn't delete luci after a reboot or openvpn for that matter.

Comment: I've install factory on my Wnr2000v3 and this didn't help.